# Run click event on multiple buttons according to their IDs in one function using JS only and not Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, events

I have buttons in div and they all have IDs. How can I make a single function in Javascript so that it performs same function for all buttons according to what button ID is clicked? I tried querySelectorAll in JS but nothing's working. Can anyone suggest an example through code?

Comment: You can post your code what you tried to do.

Comment: In button tag you can pass event paramenter to onclick handler function, `<button id="1" onclick="buttonClick(event)"> Click Me1 </button>` Then in javascript you can get id using `e.target.id` then you can perform your logic on the basis of ids
`function buttonClick(e) { console.log(e.target.id) }`.
Check this code: https://jsfiddle.net/1hpnvkr5/